# How to configure the proxy for a kafka client?

Tags: java, tcp, apache-kafka, proxy

I'm using kafka-clients library in order to create a consumer for a Kafka topic. The Kafka broker (producer) is in a restrict network, so only some IPs can access the service. So I need to configure a Proxy on Kafka client (consumer) in order to connect. In ConsumerConfig, that can be passed in Consumer constructor there isn't a proxy entry.

Method to create a consumer:

```
public static Consumer<Long, String> createConsumer() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, IKafkaConstants.KAFKA_BROKERS);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, IKafkaConstants.GROUP_ID_CONFIG);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, IKafkaConstants.MAX_POLL_RECORDS);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, IKafkaConstants.OFFSET_RESET_EARLIER);
    Consumer<Long, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(IKafkaConstants.TOPIC_NAME));
    return consumer;
}
```

how can I configure a proxy for this Consumer?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Clients must directly talk to a broker.

Any Proxy would need to know each individual address, and thus defeats the purpose of having a single load-balanced proxy anyway. The Kafka protocol handles its own load balancing and bootstrapping.

In such environments, you could convince the network team to let through SSL Kafka traffic, or install the Kafka REST Proxy and send traffic over HTTP(S) instead

Comment: I can't convince them to open the port, the only option is a proxy. I am not trying to connect a full long running consumer/producer, just trying to connect some local dev tools temporarily to test and sample data. So when we say "defeats the purpose", I get that but there is more than one purpose. So it would be incredibly useful to have proxy configuration available at least. Its pretty painful in some network environments to have no ability to proxy at all.

Comment: @justin.m.chase https://github.com/grepplabs/kafka-proxy